# How to create a functional clickable hyperlink for another web page in a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

So I'm trying to create a hyperlink so I can access a website from my shiny app, I have the following code:

```
tags$li("The data set then is filtered once again, retaining only the specimens belonging to marine species.
                           This is achieved using the", tags$a(href="www.marinespecies.org","WoRMS database",target="_blank"), ".")
```

The link appears in the app but when I try to access it just returns "Not Found"
I don't know how to solve this, thanks in advance for any answer

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42047422/create-url-hyperlink-in-r-shiny) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004959/passing-a-hyperlink-to-jira-description-field-using-r) questions.

Comment: Not really on your end they poorly setup their dns: `tags$a(href="http://www.marinespecies.org/","WoRMS database",target="_blank")`

Comment: that worked perfectly, thanks a lot